# Como colocar uma variável em <Imagem source={}/> em React Native?

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, variáveis

Estou fazendo um aplicativo React Native e estou tentando colocar uma variável na IMAGE SOURCE

```js
<FlatList
    style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}
    data={props.carregador}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    accessibilityElementsHidden={true}
    renderItem={({ item }) =>
        <Image source={require(item)} style={styles.iconLink} />
    }

/>
```

Mas não sei como usar uma variável, pois o caminho é local, e estou tentando usar o caminho local para testes.

```js
props.carregador.forEach((carr, id) => {
    link = link + carr;
    console.log(link);
    console.log(carr);
    linksCarr.push(link)
    link = "../../../assets/VetoresPNG/"

});
```

Estou usando o código de cima para pegar o array no arquivo e coloquei para ter o link.